# How did the Idiom "Tit for Tat "get the current usage?

Tags: word-usage, etymology, cultural-phrases

I have referred to the dictionary and found the following meanings.

**Tit** -a small bird that searches acrobatically for insects among foliage and branches.

**Tat**  - Low quality

*Tit for Tat* means The infliction of an Injury or Insult in return for one that one has suffered.

In Indian Languages  we have a similar Idiom " Beating the dog with cheppals for its bite".

How does the Idiom has got the meaning when ' Tit ' and 'Tat' have altogether nothing to do with the meaning ?

It is not duplicate because I have  known almost the similar Idiom in my mother tongue.
 some Idioms are almost the same all over the world.
For example, He spends money like water.
Besides I have tried to get the meaning of the  Idiom by trying to know the meanings of the Words" Tit" and "Tat"
In the previous post the meanings of the words were not mentioned.I have not seen the post earlier either

Comment: Look in [Phrases.org.uk](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/tit-for-tat.html).

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth I have seen the usage in th link.Thank you very much

Comment: Your question is wrong - 'tit' and 'tat' do not mean that in this context.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Tit for tat"—Where does this come from?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19892/tit-for-tat-where-does-this-come-from)

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth, If you think this question is not suitable for ELU, Please migrate it to ELL immediately. I do not think all the questions on your site are based on research and of very high level.you seem to be very particular about my questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tit for tat** [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=tit)

> 1550s, possibly an alteration of tip for tap "blow for blow," from tip
>   (v.3) "tap" + tap "touch lightly." Perhaps influenced by tit (n.2)

and the [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/64677554?redirectedFrom=tit%20for%20tat#eid)

> A response in kind to something, esp. an injury or insult, that one
>   has received or suffered; a retaliatory action or sequence of actions;
>   retaliation. In later use also as a parenthetic or interjectional
>   phrase.

As in:

> 2011   J. C. Hormel & E. Martin Fit to Serve xvi. 217   As we
>   struggled for those last two votes, the tit for tat continued.

Hard to pin any sexual connotatation to **tit** in this phrase, especially with alterations over time (*tip ~ tit* - as Etymonline notes.  So;  *How did the Idiom “Tit for Tat ”get the current usage?*. It started as **tip for tat** ... you slap me, I slap you!